# Adding [space] to formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transfer formula `=A2&" "&B2&". "&C2` to vba, but can't find a way to add space or dot.
So far I have:

```
Sub Concatenate()
    Range("D2:D200").Formula = "=A2&B2&C2"
    Range("D2:D200").Value = Range("D2:D200").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Formula = "=A2&"" ""&B2&"". ""&C2"`

Comment: ScottCraner thank you :)